# Interacting with a Data Grid View in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a Data Grid View pulling in rows of data from an Access Database. I would like to code it so that when a user double clicks on a row, a window opens with that particular row being opened.

In addition, I would like to code a button so that it does the same, that is open a window with the selected row data.

How can I get the selected row ID or other data in VB?

EDIT: Forgot to mention this is a DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView?

```
Private Sub dgvSource_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSource.CellContentDoubleClick
  Dim intRow As Integer = e.RowIndex
  Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = dgvSource.Rows(intRow)
  Dim drw As DataRow = DirectCast(dgvr.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
  MsgBox(drw("ID"))
End Sub
```

"ID" is the name of the column you want. For a button, set intRow based on selection.

Comment: Right this is for a DataGridView. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @paul no I think it only changes the question not sss's answer :)